# Failed implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I force to add firebase authentication to my app, but I take this error :

`Failed firebase auth 15.0.0`

It says in the solutions on the internet: `If you delete part 15.0.0 will be corrected`
but when  :15.0.0 part is deleted,it say  the authentication feature  is not added.
What can I do?
My build is here:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ppd.ment"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
```

Comment: still the same.

Comment: Post your build.gradle

Comment: question updated @Md. Asaduzzaman

Comment: remove *:15.0.0* and sync. Let me know the output

Comment: I said to I tried this in post,authentication dependencies are becoming disabled.

Comment: update build.gradle after modification

Comment: Check your gradle settings, whether **offline work** disable or not? and Click **File->Invalidate Caches/ Restart**. Thanks